How can I use multiple DAC fields in a PXProcessingJoin result?
I have a custom processing screen with its data view (using a PXProcessingJoin) selecting from / joining multiple DACs. Here's an example:
public PXProcessingJoin<GLHistoryByPeriod,
                            InnerJoin<Account,
                                On<GLHistoryByPeriod.accountID, Equal<Account.accountID>>,
                            InnerJoin<Sub,
                                On<GLHistoryByPeriod.subID, Equal<Sub.subID>>,
                            InnerJoin<Branch,
                                On<GLHistoryByPeriod.branchID, Equal<Branch.branchID>>,
                            LeftJoin<GLHistory, On<GLHistoryByPeriod.ledgerID, Equal<GLHistory.ledgerID>,
                                                And<GLHistoryByPeriod.accountID, Equal<GLHistory.accountID>,
                                                And<GLHistoryByPeriod.subID, Equal<GLHistory.subID>,
                                                And<GLHistoryByPeriod.finPeriodID, Equal<GLHistory.finPeriodID>,
                                                And<GLHistoryByPeriod.branchID, Equal<GLHistory.branchID>>>>>>,
                            InnerJoin<MasterFinPeriod, On<GLHistoryByPeriod.finPeriodID, Equal<MasterFinPeriod.finPeriodID>>>>>>>,
                            Where<GLHistoryByPeriod.finPeriodID, Equal<Constants.finPeriod>,
                                And<GLHistory.finYtdBalance, Equal<Constants.finYTDBalance>>>> FileData;

and here's the constructor:
public BlackLineFileMaint()
{
    FileData.SetProcessCaption("Process");
    FileData.SetProcessVisible(true);
    FileData.SetProcessAllCaption("Process All");
    FileData.SetProcessAllVisible(true);
    FileData.SetSelected<BlackLineFileData.selected>();
    FileData.SetProcessDelegate(GenerateFiles);
}

The problem I have is, in the process delegate (here called 'GenerateFiles'):
public static void GenerateFiles(List<GLHistoryByPeriod> records)
{
     //...code goes here - but I need more than the GLHistoryByPeriod fields..
}

How can I get the values of any of / all the other DAC fields in the PXProcessingJoin select?  Is there some other way of creating the delegate that adds the other DACs?
Thanks much..

Maybe convert to use a PXProjection to have your results as "one dac"

You can pass the entire resultset to your delegate.
Sorry, I didn't use your view, but I think you can use this as a template:
public class TestProcessing : PXGraph<TestProcessing>, IGraphWithInitialization
{
    public SelectFrom<SOOrder>
        .InnerJoin<Customer>.On<SOOrder.customerID.IsEqual<Customer.bAccountID>>
        .ProcessingView ProcessingView;

    // It is called when you press the process button
    public void Initialize()
    {
        // Filter by selected records
        var dataFromView = ProcessingView.Select()
            .Where(it => it.GetItem<SOOrder>().Selected == true)
            .ToList();
    
        ProcessingView.SetProcessDelegate(list => DoProcess(list, dataFromView));
    }

    protected static void DoProcess(List<SOOrder> list, List<PXResult<SOOrder>> dataFromView)
    {
        foreach (var data in dataFromView)
        {
            var soOrder = data.GetItem<SOOrder>();
            var soLine = data.GetItem<Customer>();
        }    
    }
}


I don't believe there is a way to pass the join table information into the delegate.  You will need to create a graph instance in your static function and use it to search the database via BQL using the Primary DAC keys.

Not sure what 'create a graph instance in your static function' means...

public static void GenerateFiles(List records)
{
GLHistoryByPeriod historyGraph = PXGraph.CreateInstance();
}
